# mysql show all if input value is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with 3 input fields and I want that the query show results if one or, two or all 3 inputs are filled in. So, I tried with is null, but it doesn't work or I can do this with a and/or query?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles";
    $sql .= " WHERE (profilename = '". $_POST["profilename"] ."' OR profilename IS NULL) ";
    $sql .= " AND (ort = '". $_POST["ort"] ."' OR ort IS NULL) ";
    $sql .= "AND (jahren = '" . $_POST["alter"] . "' OR jahren IS NULL) ";
```

Thank you a lot for you help!

Comment: Instead of 'AND' use 'OR' , as you want to show the results even if one field is filled in..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$sql = "
    SELECT * FROM profiles
    WHERE (profilename = '$_POST[profilename]' OR profilname = NULL)
    OR (ort = '$_POST[ort]' OR ort = NULL)
    OR (jahren = '$_POST[alter]' OR jahren = NULL)
";
```

**Advice:**

This `$string = "Test $test also";` is better than `$string = "Test " . $test . " also";`.
Only when you add `"`, no for `'`.

***Edited..***

Answer (score 0):

Check if any input field was filled in before you'd send query:

```
if ( isset($_POST['profilename']) || isset($_POST['ort']) || isset($_POST['alter']) ){
    $clause = "where ";
    $conds = [];
    if (!empty($_POST['profilename'])) $conds[] = "profilename = '{$_POST['profilename']}'";
    if (!empty($_POST['ort'])) $conds[] = "ort = '{$_POST['ort']}'";
    if (!empty($_POST['alter'])) $conds[] = "alter = '{$_POST['alter']}'"; 
    if(count($conds) > 0){
       $clause .= (count($conds) == 1)? $conds[0] : implode(' AND ',$conds);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles " . $clause;
        ...
        // sending query
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would update your code to the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE 1=1";
/* We use 'WHERE 1=1' so that we can chain all of our filters after this
using 'AND' (or 'OR' in other situations) regardless of whether we are using the first of these filters or not */

if(isset($_POST["profilename"]) && $_POST["profilename"] != "") 
     $sql .= " AND profilename = '". $_POST["profilename"] ."'";

if(isset($_POST["ort"]) && $_POST["ort"] != "") 
     $sql .= " AND ort = '". $_POST["ort"] ."'";

if(isset($_POST["alter"]) && $_POST["alter"] != "") 
     $sql .= " AND jahren = '" . $_POST["alter"] . "'";
```

This will check each variable before including it in the query.
For additional POST variables, just copy and paste them in the same format.

On a side note, I would suggest using prepared statements rather than dumping your POST variables inline, to avoid SQL injection exploits, etc.

Read more here: [PHP: Prepared statements and stored procedures](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thank you for your input. This sql works partially. it works just when I enter something in ort and alter. but if I use for example profilename only it does not work.